# To which URL should Google Sign In point to an Android app? (not localhost)

Tags: android, google-oauth

This is a very basic question so please be patient with me...

I'm building an app with ReactJS & Firebase and using Capacitor to convert it to Android app. Everything works well, but I'm not able to implement Google Sign In. It points to localhost and gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I'm very new to this and I'm just extremely confused at the moment. **I understand it should not point to localhost in production, but I don't understand where else it should point. A web app has a domain, but an Android app?** I just can't wrap my head around it. Could someone explain it to me like I'm 5 please?